# Is this sound normal for a Nikkor 55-200 VR?

Tags: lens, nikon, image-stabilization, sound

I just bought a Nikkor 55-200 mm 1:4-5.6G ED for my D5000 and I found that if VR is enabled two things happen after I half press the shutter, wait for the lens to focus and release it:

- I hear a loud click about two seconds later.
- Along with the sound I can see the image in the view finder shifting
  to one side just a tiny bit.

Both of the above does not happen if VR is off. Can anyone with the same lens confirm whether this is common or something to be worried about?

Comment: Two seconds?! I don't believe...

Comment: After rereading the question, the two seconds seems to be the amount of delay time before VR turns off after the shutter button is released, not how long it takes it to spin up and activate when the shutter is half pressed..

Comment: Ok ok... it is about a second :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two second delay (if it is actually that long) is the amount of time it takes for the gyros in the VR to spin up to operating speed when it is activated. The time it takes could be potentially longer when your camera's batteries are low than when they are fully charged. When you release the shutter button the VR remains active for a short time and then becomes inactive to conserve battery life. The shift you see in the viewfinder indicates when the VR becomes active or when it becomes inactive after you have released the shutter button. The sound and shift is more noticeable in some lenses than others, and will also depend on the stability of the lens at the time it kicks on or off. The sound is usually not perceived in any but the quietest of environments, but most stabilized lenses make some sort of sound when active.

Comment: Yup. This seems to be the case. I found this after posting the question here: http://www.flickr.com/groups/356195@N23/discuss/72157600282033155/